# How do I concatenate string and convert to upper case

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

first sorry for my English.

I't use powershell but I have to make a script to generate some SSRS's reports. I need to concatenate two variables and convert the result  to uppercase, the code below works fine but I't know convert the result to uppercase and put it, for example, into other variable. Thanks a lot

```
$direxcel = "C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\SSRS"
$rdl = "Sin Título"
write-host ${direxcel}\$rdl.xls
```

Comment: `"${direxcel}\$rdl.xls".ToUpper()` - PowerShell is built on .NET, so you have access to its types and their methods, such as [`System.String.ToUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.ToUpper). Pipe a value to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Member) to learn what type it is.

Comment: Try `$filePath = (Join-Path -Path $direxcel -ChildPath ($rdl + '.xls')).ToUpper()`. See [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path)

Comment: Since powershell strings are .net objects, the `toupper()` switch should do this fine. For example, `"Hello World".toupper()`

Comment: Thanks, works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To concatenate strings you can use several options.

```
$a = "first string"
$b = "second string"

$c = "$a $b"
```

or simply (but not necessarily recommended)

```
$c = $a + $b
```

To make something upper case.

```
$c = "$a $b".ToUpper()
```